# Add attribute to wrap element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, href, target

```
<a href="random-link">
<img alt="My Photo" class="profile-img" height="80" src="img" width="80">
</a>
```

how do you apply this jquery `.attr('target','_blank');` to the `<a href="link">`  so the outcome will be

```
<a href="random-link" target="_blank">
<img alt="My Photo" class="profile-img" height="80" src="img" width="80">
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case @Yusaf was using `link` as an ambiguous link, you could try this instead:

```
$('.profile-img').parent('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```